# Calculate customers who have generated revenue for the first time in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to calculate customers, who have been active the first time ever in the current period. Let's say the calculation for active customer is the following

```
MEMBER [Measures].[ActiveCustomers] AS
 Sum(
   [Customer].[Customer Id].Members, 
   IIF([Measures].[Revenue] > 0,1,NULL))
```

How, or what functions do I need to use to determine the customers whom have generated revenue the first time ever, in the current period?

Comment: How do you determine the current period? Do you want to use the last member of the bottom level of your time hierarchy? Or do you want to calculate something from the current system date? Or do you mean the `CurrentMember` of this hierarchy?

Comment: I will pivot this against a date hierarchy, let's say it's named [Calendar].[Year Month Day], and I will use the [Calendar].[Year Month Day].CurrentMember to determine the current period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, when you write "to calculate customers", you mean "to get the list of customer ids", then

```
Filter([Customer].[Customer Id].[Customer Id].Members,
       ([Calendar].[Year Month Day].CurrentMember, [Measures].[Revenue]) > 0
       AND
       Sum(null : [Calendar].[Year Month Day].CurrentMember.PrevMember, [Measures].[Revenue]) = 0
      )
```

should deliver that.
This checks that in the current period, there is revenue > 0, and the sum across all preceding periods is zero. This may fail if you have negative revenues, as then the positive and negative revenues could cancel each other, but I am assuming this is not the case here.

Comment: I wanted the count, but in that case I would need to aggregate the distinct number of customers. So let's say I wanted to get customers, who have generated revenue in this period, not in the previous, and also generated revenue 2 periods ago.... I would need to use the LastPeriod(2,[Calendar].[Year Month Day]), and add to the condition above? That should work right?

Comment: @Mez Ok, in that case, just use `Count` instead of `Filter`. And if you want customers who had revenue two periods ago that would be `([Calendar].[Year Month Day].CurrentMember.Lag(2), [Measures].[Revenue]) > 0`. And always take into account that the `CurrentMember` may be a day, a month, a year, or the all member, or whatever you have in your time hierarchy. And think how the expression would behave for all of these (if they can happen to be used in a query).

Comment: Yes that taken into consideration. In fact that is why I want to use the CurrentMember, so it would not be bound to any periods. With regards to LastPeriods(X, [Calendar]) VS CurrentMember.Lag(2) - what is the difference between the usage of these 2?

Comment: @Mez `LastPeriods(x, [Calendar])` returns a set/range of `x` members, while `Lag(x)` returns just one member, which is `x` steps away. And I understood you wanted to have customers who had revenue exactly two periods ago.